# sending variables to the added subview view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, view

I know how to retrieve variables from your parent view...
which is by doing something like this

[(mainViewController *)[self.superview] variableName];

but now i would like to know how to send variable data to a subview...

specially if i do something like this

```
ScreenTwoViewController *screen2 = [[ScreenTwoViewController alloc] init];
...
...
[self.addSubview:screen2.view];
```

in screenTwo i have a variable name Message:

I would like to send a variable message to the actual view so it can display the message in that view based on what the parent view sends it when adding the screen2 view as a subview??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have set the property for the variables in the subview like this.

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *message;`

and also synthesis it in your .m file than you can always use this

`screen2.message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"use what ever init methode that you want"];`

and dont forget to release the screen2 before the end of the method to avoid memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a setter for `Message`? If not, is it a property? Either way, I would have a getter method, `setMessage:(NSString *)msg` with the following implementation:

```
- (void)setMessage:(NSString *)msg {
    [message release];
    message = [msg retain];
    // put your code to modify your UI here
}
```

This way, you're tying the assignment of the variable with the update of the view.

Comment: i dont have a setter message in screen two view controller, i would like to know how to send a variable or set a variable string so that when i add a subview i can also set the message at the same time so the message can be displayed... when loading the view.

Comment: so... current view does following:
instantiate ScreenTwoViewController *screen2 = [[ScreenTwoViewController alloc] init]; blah blah when then [self.addSubview:screen2]; i should also somehow send a string variable so i can set a message inside screen2... so it is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new init method for `ScreenTwoViewController`. For example, `- (id) initWithMessage:(NSString *)message`.

To update the message just create a setter method `- (void)setMessage:(NSString *)newMessage`.

Comment: BTW `(mainViewController *)[[self.superview] variableName];` is actually wrong.

It should be `[(mainViewController *)[self.superview] variableName];`